# How to design base and derived classes with different return type?

Tags: c++, uml, virtual

I have a base class `Attr` (Attribute), it has two derived classes `NomAttr` (Nominal Attribute) and `NumAttr` (Numeric Attribute).

Each has a `name` member, which is always string type.

However, their `value` member differs: for `NomAttr`, I want to get its `value` of `string` type, but for `NumAttr`, I want to get its `value` of `double` type.

Virtual function does not allow different return types, so I am a little stuck here. (Initially I draw the below UML to model my intent. )

[image: UML]

---

Many people asks me to show the real problem. Here is a global view:

This is a Machine Learner.  The `Attr` is a part of instance in dataset:
A `DataSet` is consist of a list of `Ins` (instances).
An `Ins` consists of a list of `Attr`s, the count of `Attr`s and type of each `Attr` is known at run-time, parsed from an datafile supplied by user with command line argument.
Here you go:
[image]

Comment: You could use a template.

Comment: I recommend returning boost any or boost variant.

Comment: Can you show the real problem you are trying to solve and the context in which `Attr` is used? C++ is strongly typed and doesn't directly support what you want to do, but depending on the REAL need there are various mechanisms you can use (probably static or dynamic polymorphism).

Comment: @MarkB More like statically typed.

Comment: @MarkB Please see the updates.

Comment: @AlejandroDíaz But the type of `Attr` is not known until run-time

Comment: @modeller oh, I see, if you have a known set of types you could parse it and then `if(data_type == "int"){  return NumAttr(); }`? where the parsing function returns the base class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So based on your updates I don't think you need any inheritance to handle your attr at all. Instead, have the base `Attr` contain the value directly as a `boost::variant<double, std::string>` and since you know what type it will be you can simply get the correct type out of the variant for each attribute.

Comment: Thanks. I need to try this out.

Answer (score 2):

Using templates:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T> class Attribute{
public:
    Attribute() : mAttr(T()) { }
    Attribute(T pAttr) : mAttr(pAttr) { }
    T getAttr() { return mAttr; }
private:
    T mAttr;
};

class NumAttr : public Attribute<int>{
public:
    NumAttr() : Attribute<int>(0) { }
    NumAttr(int pAttr) : Attribute<int>(pAttr) { }
};

class NomAttr : public Attribute<std::string>{
public:
    NomAttr() : Attribute<std::string>(std::string()) { }
    NomAttr(std::string pAttr) : Attribute<std::string>(pAttr) { }
};
int main(void){
    NomAttr name(std::string("test"));
    NumAttr number(1);
    std::cout << "Name: " << name.getAttr() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Number: " << number.getAttr() << std::endl;
}
```

Note that there's actually no need for derived classes, you could just use `Attribute<int>` and `Attribute<std::string>` or whatever other type you need.

EDIT: this won't work if the types aren't known at compile-time, see @MarkB answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need just one `template derived class`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Base
{
public:
    virtual T getValue() = 0;
protected:
    T value;
};

template<typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T>
{
public:
    Derived(T v)
    {
        value = v;
    }
    T getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived<string> d1 = Derived<string>("test");
    Derived<double> d2 = Derived<double>(3.14);

    cout << d1.getValue() << endl;
    cout << d2.getValue() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Either use a template like the other user suggested or instead of returning a value pass the value to be set by reference.

Psuedo Code EX:

```
//this code has your problem
virtual int func();

int func(int a) override
{return a + 3};
int a = func(3);//a will be 6

//this code does not
virtual void procedure();

void procedure(int a, int* b) override
{*b=a+3};
int a;
func(3,&a);//a will be 6
```